# How to see the underlying type in Visual Studio (2015/2013) when in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

When running an application debug mode, after hitting a break point, the only way I've known to get the 'type' of the object that has focus (i.e. an object referenced as an interface or parent type) is by right clicking it and either selecting 'Add Watch' or 'Quick Watch', then looking under the 'Type` column.

Are there any other (possibly quicker ways) of retrieving an objects type in Visual Studio?

Comment: use the immediate window and type "mybject.GetType().Name"

Comment: I see the underlying type by just hovering over the object.

Comment: @itsme86 I have a feeling this is just returning `this.ToString()` which may well be overridden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to Debug > Windows > Locals while debugging this will show all the variables in your solution at the time of breakpoint.

You should also be able to see the type of each variable. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `Locals` window:

[image]

The `Type` column will show you the runtime type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping to a lot of objects (or the function get's called a lot of times) instead of using the immediate window, you could als just write the code using something like console.write() to write it to the console. Then keep an eye on the output window.

Probably want to use

```
#if DEBUG 
#endif
```

around the statement.